# Finding value of ENUM from object in ArrayList from different class

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

Main class. Trying to iterate through cards in hand, and check if the value exceeds 21.

```
int handValue; 
for(int z = 0; z<hand.size(); z++){ //iterate through cards in hand
    Cards card = hand.get(z);       //to add values and check if bust (21)
    System.out.println(valueofcards);
    // hand.get(z).RankPoints()
    // Rank.valueOf(hand.get(z), a)
}
System.out.println("Bust.");//check if bust
```

The Cards class contains this enum, with method RankPoints(). I'm trying to access this method from the main class, however much google-foo I try I can't find a solution. I originally thought the problem was trying to use it from an ArrayList, but I don't think that's the problem.

```
public enum Rank{
        ACE(11), DEUCE(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10);

        private int RankPoints;

    Rank (int points){
        this.RankPoints = points;
    }

    public int RankPoints(){
        return this.RankPoints;
    }

}
```

And here is the card constructor using the enum:

```
private final Rank rank;
private final Suit suit;

Cards(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `hand.get(z).RankPoints()` You seem to be calling it on a reference of type `Cards`, not `Rank`.

Comment: Do you actually have an instance of `Rank` anywhere in your code? Simply defining an enum within a class doesn't create any instances of the enum.

Comment: hand.get(z).RankPoints() gives me an error. Cannot find symbol? I tried it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Card class has a `getRank()` method, then you will want to use it:

```
Rank rank = hand.get(z).getRank();
int points = rank.RankPoints(); // note methods should begin with a lower case letter.
```

Then you can get the points from this Rank object.

If Card does not have a `Rank getRank()` "getter" method, then it needs one.

e.g.,

```
int handValue; 
for(int z = 0; z<hand.size(); z++){ //iterate through cards in hand
    Cards card = hand.get(z);       //to add values and check if bust (21)
    Rank rank = card.getRank();  // better make sure Card has this method
    int points = rank.RankPoints();
    handValue += points;

    // check now that it's not > 21
    // ?? System.out.println(valueofcards);
}
```

Again the Cards class will need a getRank() getter method:

```
public Rank getRank() {
   return rank;
}
```

As an aside, I would name your Cards class, Card, since it defines a blueprint for a single playing card. Yes, you can make instances with it for up to 52 separate card, but you use one same blueprint (the class) for each card (the instance). If I had a class that holds a bunch of cards, I'd possibly use a name like Cards, but you could also use singular here too such as Hand for a card hand or Deck for a deck of cards.

Comment: Thanks, just needed to make the getRank() method